# Block rendering issues in Magento 1.9.2.0

Tags: layout, ce-1.9.2.0, custom-block

having some weird issue in Magento 1.9.2.0

I've got my local.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="leftmenu" as="leftmenu"
                   template="catalog/product/view/left.phtml />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

When I try to do: `$this->getChildHtml('leftmenu');` it doesn't render anything, if I var_dump it it shows string '' (0)

However if I change the reference to root to content then it renders, but below all the html.

If I then change it back to root and change `$this->getChildHtml('leftmenu');` to `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('leftmenu')->toHtml();` it will then render as it should... any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: You want show left navigation on product detail page ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is - catalog_product_view doesn't use root to create blocks - it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/template" name="product.left.menu" as="product.left.menu"
                   template="catalog/product/view/left.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="product.tabs" as="product.tabs"
                   template="catalog/product/view/tabs/tabs.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="product.related" as="product.related"
                   template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="leftmenu" as="leftmenu"
                   template="catalog/product/view/left.phtml />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Call it using below

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('leftmenu');
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032973/where-is-the-content-of-php-echo-this-getchildhtml-right)

Comment: That just renders the code underneath the content, without even needing to use $this->getChildHtml()

Comment: Updated answer check it.